# how do i show a progress indicator until the server responds?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, tomcat

I have an application in which a page takes about 1 minute to load. It is a large page with a lot of calculation and other stuff.

I want to display a progress indicator until the server gives me a reply. Does anyone have any idea for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show progress bar on web page until web page is fully loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557271/how-to-show-progress-bar-on-web-page-until-web-page-is-fully-loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it takes a long time on the server to create the HTML of the page, then there's no way of showing the page with a loading message/progress indicator, and then have the content show up.

The only way I can think of is loading the page with just the loading message/progress indicator, and then making an AJAX call to actually get the content (which takes a long time to get generated).

Comment: I can't use ajax there as i am using jsp and data is displayed from lists in jsp.

Answer (score 2):

You need to display the loader, ajax load the content and when the Ajax request completes hide the loader and show the content or simply replace the loader with the new data.

A naive implementation could look something like this and would replace the contents of #content with whatever is returned by the url /newcontent.

```
<div id="content">
 <img src="/path/to/loader.gif" />
</div>

<script>
 $("#content").load("/newcontent");
</script>
```

or in your case where it looks like you actually want to replace the entire page replace the entire body contents with:

```
$('body').load('newpage.html');
```

Comment: I can't use ajax there as i am using jsp and data is displayed from lists in jsp.

Comment: why not? 1 show loader. 2 make Ajax request against controller mapped url (jsp generation takes long time ..) 3 finally jsp generation is completed and request returns and jquery replaces the loader with the content from the jsp. Should not be a problem, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code while it display over the upload.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.blockUI();
    //load your editor here
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.unblockUI();
    }, 10000);
}); ​
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a div in your page as a blanket, initially it will show and block the whole page. And hide the div in 's onload handler. This is a plain, may be not a good solution.